# Using SmtpClient(C#), SMTP_SSL(Python) with same setting but SMTP_SSL only works

Tags: python, c#, email, smtp, smtpclient

I try to make a program that have to send e-mail.
At first, I tried to use C# and SmtpClient class.

```
public static void SendEmail(string strTitle, string strContents)
        {
            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();

            mm.Subject = strTitle;
            mm.Body = strContents;
            mm.From = new MailAddress("sender@email.net");
            mm.To.Add("receiver@email.net");

            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.email.net", 465);
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ID", "PW");
            SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            //SmtpServer.Port = 465;            
            SmtpServer.Timeout = 1500;

            try
            {
                SmtpServer.Send(mm);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                SmtpServer.Dispose();
                mm.Dispose();
            }
            
            return;
        }
```

Unfortunately, that code didn't work.
After tons of trying, I tried same function with python.

```
class sendMail:
    def send(self, strTitle, strContents):
        try:
            toEmail = 'receiver@email.net'
            fromEmail = 'sender@email.net'
            TitleEmail = strTitle

            msg = "\r\n".join([
                "From: " + fromEmail,
                "To: " + toEmail,
                "Subject: " + TitleEmail,
                "",
                strContents
            ])

            conn = SMTP_SSL("smtp.email.net:465")
            conn.ehlo()

            loginId = 'ID'
            loginPassword = 'PW'
            conn.login(loginId, loginPassword)

            conn.sendmail(fromEmail, toEmail, msg)
            conn.close()
            return 'Success to send emails.'

        except Exception as e:
            return "Failed. error" + str(e)
```

Surprisingly, It worked.

Same PC, same Anti-virus and firewall, same smtp server, but results were different.
To send email with c#, what should I do? What's wrong?

#Add information.
with C# code, this exception occured.

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out.
   Location: System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   Location: XCoinAPIConsoleClient.XCoinAPI.SendEmail(String strTitle, String strContents) File D:\Code\Bithumb_20170414_RESTFulAPI-C_s\xcoin_api_client.cs:Line 191
```

Comment: What does "that code didn't work" actually mean? Hunch: does the note section in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl?view=net-6.0#remarks) apply?

Comment: In the C# code, add the try-catch block to the entire code, not just for the `Send` method call. Then for any of the other exception you would come to know. For instance if the network credentials fail, etc

Comment: Sorry for not enough information. I added more information about error.

Comment: Hey. The answer I've posted was deleted. Hopefully you've read it before it was deleted. I suppose wishing you luck wouldn't get this comment deleted but you never know...